# Select 0 sum for empty years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this seems to be a very common question and yet I can't seem to find an answer that easily transitions into my issue. Typically people are looking for a 0 for missing months, mine is with years.  I'm just looking for each product that has been sold in the last 10 years to show for those 10 years the amount or a 0 if none.

My code that shows years where there have been sales:

```
select upper(_producttype) as _product, YEAR(_date) as _year, 
coalesce(SUM(s._quantity * pu._usdperunit),0)  as _profit  
from QualityControl.dbo._Shipment s
join QualityControl.dbo._ProductUnits pu
on pu._prodid = s._productid
where year(GETDATE())-YEAR(_date) < 11
and upper(_producttype) != 'EQUIPMENT'
group by YEAR(_date), _producttype

order by  _producttype, YEAR(_date)
```

My query that gives me a list of the last 10 years (+ current):

```
select distinct YEAR(_date) as _year
from QualityControl.dbo._Shipment s
where year(GETDATE())-YEAR(_date) < 11
and _producttype != 'Equipment'
order by  YEAR(_date)
```

I have tried a union with _profit being 0. I have tried a cross join, but seemed to be getting too many columns at that point. Any help at this point would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a unique key for each row in your table? I'm not sure I fully understand the question at this point--can you clarify a little more what you are looking for? A product type that has not had a sale in the last 10 years?

Comment: Haha, I guess it does sound a little strange. I do have unique keys for each row, luckily Nenand was able to help  me out. As for the products, we have some years a product had 0 sales, or a product that was sold 7 years ago and was replaced, so the years after that I wanted it to be represented by a 0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your queries you can do following with them.

- Just put your grouped data in one CTE
- years in another
- create third subset that's combination of distinct products and years
- LEFT JOIN between combinations and your data

.

```
WITH CTE_Data AS 
(
    select upper(_producttype) as _product, YEAR(_date) as _year, 
    coalesce(SUM(s._quantity * pu._usdperunit),0)  as _profit  
    from QualityControl.dbo._Shipment s
    join QualityControl.dbo._ProductUnits pu
    on pu._prodid = s._productid
    where year(GETDATE())-YEAR(_date) < 11
    and upper(_producttype) != 'EQUIPMENT'
    group by YEAR(_date), _producttype
)
, CTE_Years AS 
(
    select distinct YEAR(_date) as _year
    from QualityControl.dbo._Shipment s
    where year(GETDATE())-YEAR(_date) < 11
    and _producttype != 'Equipment'
)
, CTE_AllCombo AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT y._year, d._Product
    FROM CTE_Years y
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Data d
)
SELECT c._year, c._product, COALESCE(d._profit, 0) AS _profit
FROM CTE_AllCombo c
LEFT JOIN CTE_Data d ON d._year = c._year and d._product = c._product
```

Comment: This works exactly as I had hoped. I will have to try and figure out all the code here as it is more complex than I had thought it would be :)  Thanks!